# Is React compatible with Odoo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, odoo

I want to use my component library written in react JS in my Odoo website. Is it possible, compatible? if not is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues are you getting?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I've installed Odoo instance. I wonder if it is possible to embed some reactjs into Odoo website.